# Write a function that returns past tense of given verb

Tags: code-golf, string

### Challenge

> Write a function which takes an argument which is a verb, and returns the past tense of the verb. (Assume that the verb is regular)

### Past tense

Note: consider y as neither consonant nor vowel.

Normally, just adding `ed` after the end of verb makes the past tense of the verb.

Ex: `jump` → `jumped`, `ask` → `asked`

However, there are other rules.

- If the last character of the given verb is `e`, just add `d`.

  Ex: `love` → `loved`, `move` → `moved`
- If the verb is ended with a consonant + `y`, then change `y` to `i`, and add `ed`.

  Ex: `study` → `studied`, `cry` → `cried`
- However, if the verb is ended with a vowel + `y`, then just add `ed`.

  Ex: `play` → `played`, `stay` → `stayed`
- If a verb is ended with a vowel and a consonant, then write the consonant one more time, and add `ed`.

  Ex: `stop` → `stopped`, `plan` → `planned`
- However, if a verb is ended with multiple vowels + a consonant or single vowel + multiple consonants, then just add `ed`.

  Ex: `look` → `looked`, `jump` → `jumped`

There are more rules but let's care above rules only. For example, according to above rule, `visit` → `visitted`.

### Winner

Since this is code golf, the shortest code that correctly returns past tenses wins.

### Example (JS, 127)

`function f(x){return x.replace(/([^aeiouy])y$/,'$1i').replace(/([^aeiouy][aeiou])([^aeiouy])$/,'$1$2$2').replace(/e$/,'')+'ed'}`

Comment: Now that's a nice challenge.

Comment: inverse stemming! interesting! I'll try to give a try when I get back home :)

Comment: Any solution that's shorter than 1800 characters is incorrect (irregular verbs).

Comment: @Quandary That's why I said '(Assume that the verb is regular)'

Comment: @Quandary: Not quite true... see [Belisarius' answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3947/3145).

Comment: something directly related to it, can there be a function which returns the third form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**sed, 76 characters**

Does a sed script count as a function for this problem?

```
s/\([^aeiou]\)y$/\1i/
s/\([^aeiou][aeiou]\)\([^aeiouy]\)$/\1\2\2/
s/e\?$/ed/
```

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica 43 chars

```
f=WordData[#,"InflectedForms","List"][[1]]&
```

Usage:

```
f /@ {"call", "try", "use", "wash", "play", "stop", "look"}

{"called", "tried", "used", "washed", "played", "stopped", "looked"}
```

Also:

```
f /@ {"buy", "run", "swim"}

{"bought", "ran", "swam"}
```

Comment: You don't think that a dictionary look-up is kinda cheating? :-)

Comment: @Simon Definitively no. WordData is part of the language :)

Answer (score 3):

### Groovy - 111 characters

```
v={it==~'[aeiou]'};p={s->r=s[0..-2];a=s[-1];b=v s[-2];(a=='e'?r:a=='y'?!b?r+'i':s:v(s[-3])|!b|v(a)?s:s+a)+'ed'}

assert ['jump', 'ask', 'love', 'move', 'study', 'cry', 'play', 'stay', 'stop', 'plan', 'look'].collect { p(it) } == ['jumped', 'asked', 'loved', 'moved', 'studied', 'cried', 'played', 'stayed', 'stopped', 'planned', 'looked']
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl 5 (82 characters):

```
sub f{$_=pop;$C='[^aeiouy]';s/($C)y$/$1i/;s/($C[aeiou])($C)$/$1$2$2/;s/e?$/ed/;$_}
```

I am sure it can be improved.

Answer (score 2):

## C - <strike>120</strike> 119 characters

In typical C style, the function f updates a string buffer in place, assuming that the caller has reserved enough space for up to three extra characters.  The second argument should be given as 0.  The declaration of the global state variable `l` is included in the total character count.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

l;void f(b,i)char*b;{*b?f(b+1,i/2+4*!strchr("aeiouy",l=*b)):(i-5?*--b=l=='y'&i/2?'i':l:(*b=l),strcpy(b+=l!='e',"ed"));}

int main()
{
  char b[10000];
  while (gets(b)) {
    f(b,0);
    puts(b);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Explanation: The function iterates over the characters recursively. The second argument `i` encodes which of the previous three characters were consonants in its bottom three bits.  At the end of the string, if `i==5` then the last three characters were a consonant, a vowel and a consonant, and thus the last character must be duplicated.  Similarly, if bit 1 of `i` indicates that the second-to-last character was a consonant and the last character is 'y', then the 'y' is replaced by 'i'.

Answer (score 1):

#### Scala 199 <strike>273</strike> chars

```
def v(c:Char)="aeiouy" contains c
def p(o:String)={val s=o.reverse
if(s(0)=='e')o+"d"else
if(!v(s(1))&& s(0)=='y')o.replaceAll("y$","ied")else
if(!v(s(0))&& v(s(1))&& !v(s(2)))o+s(0)+"ed"else
o+"ed"}
```

Invocation:

```
val li = List ("move", "cry", "plan", "play", "look")
li map p
```

My first approach was much longer, by moving the if-else-cascade to a list=> to a function:

```
type S=String
def f(l:List[(Boolean,S)]):S=if(l(0)._1)l(0)._2 else f(l.tail)
def v(c:Char)="aeiouy" contains c
def c(o:S)={val s=o.reverse
f(List((s(0)=='e',o+"d"),(!v(s(1))&& s(0)=='y',o.replaceAll("y$","ied")),(!v(s(0))&& v(s(1))&& !v(s(2)),o+s(0)+"ed"),(true,o+"ed")))}
```

Maybe the approach is interesting. Degolfed and explained:

```
// just for shortening
type S=String
/* take a list of Booleans and Strings, and return early
   if a Boolean is true. This approach would work, 
   if there where much more conditions, I guess.
*/
def doFirst (list: List[(Boolean, S)]): S =
  if (list(0)._1) list(0)._2 else doFirst (list.tail)
// vocal - is it a vocal
def v(c:Char)="aeiouy" contains c
// here is the key function
def toPast(o:S)={
  // reversing the String allows easy access to the last elements, 
  // without considering how long the string is.
  val s=o.reverse
  doFirst (List (
    (s(0)=='e', o+"d"),
    (!v(s(1)) && s(0)=='y', o.replaceAll("y$","ied")),
    (!v(s(0)) && v(s(1)) && !v(s(2)), o+s(0)+"ed"),
    (true, o+"ed")
  ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 101 characters

Probably can be smaller.

```
def f x;x.sub(/([^aeiouy])y$/,'\1i').sub(/([^aeiouy][aeiou])([^aeiouy])$/,'\1\2\2').sub(/e$/,'')+'ed';end
```

Usage:

```
f("try")  #=> "tried"
f"call"   #=> "called"
```

Comment: Use Ruby 1.9 lambda syntax `f=->(x){...}` to get shorter code. Also `aeiouy` IMHO should be a constant.

Answer (score 0):

### Poop - 72 characters

```
f[s]s^6pow>4<<last&8*(/"ed""id""eid"/|out|flush)+rep'y'1-2-3"aeiou"ord#s
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python - 147

```
def f(v):T,x,m='aeiou',"ed",v[-1];return[[[v+x,v+m+x][v[-2]in T and m and v[-3]not in T],[v+x,v[:-1]+"ied"][v[-2]not in T]][m=='y'],v+"d"][m=='e']
```